# How to enable Player in react with tone.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api, tone.js

I have read the documentation of tone.js a few times now but still no idea why my code isn't working.

According to this post https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Using-Tone.js-with-React-or-Vue
we are supposed to use the `Sampler` for audio files/samples instead of `Player` as stated in the [tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) documentation.

Provided is a hyperlink to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tone-sampler-example-ykd53) in which you can see a demo.

I uploaded the sound-file of my project and was able to play it without any issues.

In my project though I get the following error in the console:

> url key is neither a note or midi pitch: Sound

As far as I understand that means the sampler is not able to process the file.

Which is probably why the Player was introduced.

I run a local server via Chrome and the latest tone.js version.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './DrumMachine.css';
import Button from '../buttons/Button';
import { Player, Buffer } from 'tone';
import Sound from '../audio/sound.wav' //src\audio\sound.wav

var buff1 = new Buffer(Sound);

class DrumMachine extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

        this.player = new Player(
            { Sound },
            { onload: () => {
                console.log('loaded');
                this.setState({isLoaded: true});
            }}

        ).toDestination();
    }

    handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state.isLoaded);
        this.player.start();
       
    }

    render() {

        const { isLoaded } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div className='drum-machine'>
              <Button disabled={!isLoaded} onClick={this.handleClick}>Btn1</Button>
              <Button>Btn2</Button>
              <Button>Btn3</Button>
              <Button>Btn4</Button>
              <Button>Btn5</Button>
              <Button>Btn6</Button>
              <Button>Btn7</Button>
              <Button>Btn8</Button>    
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DrumMachine;
```

I had changed `Master` to `Destination` as the method is no longer being used in newer versions according to the documentation. I tried it before in various ways to no avail. Only works in the sandbox with the Sampler on v.13.4.9.

If I run the code above I get: Error: ***"buffer is either not set or not loaded"***

UPDATE: I got the player running but ran myself into another problem which has been discussed in the following thread. You can find the solution in the codesandbox at the bottom of the post.

Follow me : [How to enable volume slider of Player tone.js inside of useEffect hook(react)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595019/how-to-enable-volume-slider-of-player-tone-js-inside-of-useeffect-hookreact)

Comment: ?!?!?! I've left a link to another thread which contains the answer **because** I felt it might be useful for others. I didn't feel the need to copy/paste the exact same code in this thread; ergo the link.

Comment: please add the solution you found as an answer, for the benefit of others facing similar issues, or delete this question as obsolete.